# Fulltext query IN BOOLEAN MODE fails with words having less than 3 characters

Tags: full-text-search, myisam

I have a MyISAM table with a FULLTEXT index, but search queries IN BOOLEAN MODE with keywords having less than 3 characters fail.

This work:

```
SELECT col FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST('+am7 +gm7' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But this does not:

```
SELECT col FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST('+am +gm' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

It returns "am" **OR** "gm", but I want both words: "am" **AND** "gm".

If I run `show variables like 'ft_min%'`, it shows 1 so setting ft_min_word_len has been successful. Also i've rebuild (and repaired the table, just in case) the FULLTEXT index after I rebooted the server. But this query still fails.

Edit: It's an issue related to stopwords, default settings are applied, my custom list is bypassed. Here is what I configured:

```
ft_min_word_len=1
innodb_ft_min_token_size=1
innodb_ft_enable_stopword=1
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table=my_table/_ft_stopwords
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table=my_table/_ft_stopwords
```

Any idea why db isn't using my list? Or what I could do? Thanks!

Comment: See if InnoDB's FULLTEXT does the job 'correctly'.

Comment: I had tried that too, but it does not. It's like my custom list of stopwords is overriden.

Comment: Switch to InnoDB.

Comment: As I said above, I've tried innodb too, but I'm having the same issue. For some reason my custom list is not used. Maybe the path is incorrect? The only thing that works is disabling stopwords (`ft_stopword_file=""` and `innodb_ft_enable_stopword=0`), but that's a workaround and not a real solution.

Comment: Please build a short test case so we can experiment with it, too.  And, perhaps that will lead to a clean bug report.